# Prevent simultaneously tapping on views

Tags: ios, swift

I have many views, and I want the behaviour that when I tap at the first view, other views interaction will be disabled until the task finish.

Now, my code looks like this.

```
private var lock = false
@IBAction func firstViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if lock{
        return
    }
    lock = true
    doSomeTask{ error in
        println("finish 1!!")
        self.lock = false
    }
}
@IBAction func secondViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if lock{
        return
    }
    lock = true
    doSomeTask{ error in
        println("finish 2!!")
        self.lock = false
    }
}
```

I am wondering. Is there another elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false` and `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true` to lock and unlock it. Be careful you app may be unresponsive if you don't unlock the view properly.